# Buffer Overflow Exception in Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

Getting the below error while streaming data from Kafka using spark structured streaming.
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffer overflow when available data size(16384)>=application buffer size (16384)`

The consumption still continues after getting this exception, but I want to know whether I am losing data because of this and also how to resolve this issue.